# How can I move a custom taxonomy and its data from one post type to another?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, taxonomy

I'm writing a data conversion to merge one custom post type (Faculty) into another (Person).

Merging the actual CPT records is straightforward, but the two post types have similar custom taxonomies that I need to deal with:

- Faculty has a custom taxonomy, `faculty-type`, *which has both terms and data*
- Person has an *empty* custom taxonomy, `person-type`, *which has neither terms nor data*

I'd like to move the `faculty-type` taxonomy, including both terms and data, into the empty `person-type` taxonomy—so that when the Faculty-to-Person conversion finishes, all of the `faculty-type` data will be present as `person-type` data for the new Person records.

How can move the taxonomy data from Faculty to Person?

Answer (score 2):

One simple query will accomplish this Assuming a `wp_` table prefix:

`UPDATE wp_term_taxonomy SET taxonomy = 'person-type' WHERE taxonomy = 'faculty-type';`

Note that if the target taxonomy wasn't empty, additional work would be needed to avoid conflicting terms.